# Non-European Citizen wants to marry and bring wife to Italy

Tags: visa, italy

I'm currently living in Italy as PhD student. I aim to getting married, and, then, bringing my wife to Italy. Dos anyone know the procedure? I know she may apply for visa from familiar reasons, and that I need to require a nulla osta in Italy. Right? 
Can I require the nulla osta before marrying? Because I'm travelling home (Brazil) and getting married there, then returning to Italy.

Can anyone add something to this?

Grazie

Comment: Where is "home"?

Comment: Just updated, sorry. Brazil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to invite her with family visa, than marry her in Italy. After 10 years you can ask citizenship, but until you are a student she can stay with you in Italy.